# Xamarin.Forms set size of custom view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I set the size, in xaml, of a custom view or, more specifically, a custom BoxView? Currently, the view takes up the entire device size instead of the requested 20x20.

[image]

Here's my xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Beltpack"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Beltpack.Views;assembly=Beltpack"
             x:Class="Beltpack.MainPage">

  <controls:bpButton Height="20" Width="20" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />

</ContentPage>
```

---

My button deriving from BoxView (currently doesn't do anything)

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Beltpack.Views {
    public class bpButton : BoxView {

        public bpButton() { }

    }

}
```

---

And my custom renderer

```
using Android.Graphics;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Beltpack.Views;
using Beltpack.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(bpButton), typeof(bpButtonRenderer))]

namespace Beltpack.Droid {
    public class bpButtonRenderer : BoxRenderer {

        public bpButtonRenderer() {}

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            bpButton btn = (bpButton)this.Element;

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua;

            canvas.DrawCircle((int)(btn.WidthRequest * .5), (int)(btn.HeightRequest * .5), (int)(btn.WidthRequest * .5), paint);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if WidthRequest and HeightRequest have the correct values at the OnDraw function? I suspect you must force a redraw on the OnElementChanged function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`, you must also set your `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` settings.

Why? I have no clue, but that has been the solution suggested elsewhere and has consistently worked for me.

It looks like you want it in the center, so you could simply write

```
<controls:bpButton 
    Height="20"
    Width="20" 
    HeightRequest="20"
    WidthRequest="20"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it's slightly off centered... But I should hopefully be able to figure it out....